# AngularJs ng-repeat does not dispay values even when model has values

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angularjs

I am using AngularJs to display list of names provided by a nodejs route 'api/getItems'
which returns  following

```
router.get('/getItems',function(req,res,next){

var model = [{"_id":"53f4cde40864fca70c2434cf","name":"John Smith"},
                 {"_id":"23f4bde40864fba70c2434cf","name":"Smith John"},
                 {"_id":"592f4cde40864fca70c2434cf","name":"Albert Test"}]; 
      res.json(model);


});
```

Please find my html code and angular code ( app.js) in this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ve6k08aq/)

This code appears to be pretty straightforward  and simple . I am new to angularjs and hence i cant make out what is the issue. The list iterates for the number of objects but does not display name.I have tried debug using Angular Batarang and found the following.

[image]

Can someone help me with what i am doing wrong here?  Thank you very much

adding my angular code below.

```
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

app.factory('TestService', function ($http, $q) {

    return ({
        getItems : getItems 
    });

    function getItems(){

        var request = $http({
                             method: "Get",
                             url: "api/getitems"                        
                            });

        return( request.then( handleSuccess, handleError ) );
    }

    function handleError( response ) {

        if (! angular.isObject( response.data ) ||! response.data.message) {

            return( $q.reject( "An unknown error occurred." ) ); 
        }          
        return( $q.reject( response.data.message ) ); 
    }

    function handleSuccess( response ) { 
        return( response.data ); 
    }


});

app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', 'TestService', function ($scope, TestService) {

    $scope.model= [];
    $scope.model.TestList= [];

    loadRemoteData();

    function loadRemoteData(){
        TestService.getItems().then(function(data){
                applyRemoteData(data);
        });
    }

    function applyRemoteData( WorkItems ) {
        $scope.model.TestList = WorkItems;
    }    

}]);
```

html snippet :

```
<body ng-app="sampleApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestController"> 
             <div  ng-repeat="item in model.TestList">
                <p>Name :</p> {{item.name}} 
             </div>             
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you have a question about angular, please include the *angular*-code in the question. Also consider [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co) if you want to provide an example with multiple files.

Comment: I didn't change nothing, only URL; See working example here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/T3aHvQzbrgAEoZafdyD1?p=preview

Comment: @Yoshi My angular code is provided in the fiddle along with html

Comment: @NewtonCode The problem is, that whenever jsfiddle goes down, or the link is broken for some other reason, your question will become unusable for future visitors. That's why you should allways include the code in question **in** your question. See: [Help Center > Asking: Help others reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks @Yoshi , i have now included angular code as well along with the question . Could you please provide some clue as to why $http.get is not working in this situation.Seems Hard coding json works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I checked with your jsfiddle , there will be a problem with your `$http.get(url);`

as i see your are not getting correct promise object check with get call.

So i tried with mock data By forking and did few changes in jsfiddle and removed some script tags in html.

[here is the updated jsfiddle which works fine which your looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/dulcedilip/ud0677ca/12/)

Comment: what am i doing wrong in $http.get ? yes this is working with mock data. but i cant figure our why it is working

Comment: can you check with your factory service ,which is not returning promise object. and i removed script like jquery and other script which you included.

Comment: Factory service is returning promise object fine. I am returning 3 objects and ng-repeat loops for 3 times , but it seems it cant access properties. I have attached a screenshot of inspecting using angular baatrang . It shows that objects are bound to view . I do not understand why this happens.

Comment: As per  Maxim Shoustin i also checked with plunker too it is working.There is problem with your jsfiddle better you can work with new one. work with plunker